# Htaccess authorization for specific url

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, authorization

Am writing a piece of authorization rule in ht-access for a rest framework am building. I want to restrict post request to all url except one. Here is the code

```
# Block all post request to every part of domain except data
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
Rewrite Rule .*/data/?$ [R,L]
Rewrite Rule .* - [F,NC]
```

Please can anybody help me figure out where I went wrong because I get a 403 error every time I make a post request to any url on the framework